# ElasticSearch getting the last version of document

Tags: elasticsearch

I store some documents in index "blog".

When I open URL http://localhost:9200/blog/post/90?pretty=true by browser 
I have the different value in "_version" field. ElasticSearch store 2 version of my document and return it randomly.

How to get the last document?

Comment: ES always returns the most recent version, you don't need to worry about specifying the version you want.

Comment: The documents which returning is different. One oldest than other

Comment: URL http://localhost:9200/blog/post/90?pretty=true&preference=_primary - always return correct document

Comment: you can add the "explain":true in your query and will probably see that the two different documents are actually from different nodes.

Answer (score 5):

The _version property is used to implement optimistic locking. There cannot be two documents with a different version in the index. At least not in the same shard. Their might be a very short time frame in which the replicate shard can have an older version. Each update to the documents increases the version number. You can find more information about this in this blog post:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/versioning/